# Image of the veronese map for the rational normal curve

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Given the veronese mapping for n=1
\begin{align*}
 v_d:\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})&\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^d(\mathbb{C})\\
 \langle z_0,z_1\rangle&\longmapsto\langle z_0^d,z_0^{d-1}z_1,\cdots,z_1^d\rangle
 \end{align*}
my goal is to show that

> $$v_d(\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}))=Z(\langle
>  x_ix_j-x_{j-1}x_{i+1}\rangle).$$

The inclusion $\subset$ is clear.

The other inclusion however I need a little help.

**Attempt:**
we let $\langle x_0,\cdots ,x_d\rangle\in \mathbb{P}^d$, which satisfies $x_ix_j-x_{j-1}x_{i+1}=0$.
Then let $i$ such that we always assume $x_i$ is non zero. Since $x_i^2=x_{i-1}x_{i+1}$, we may assume by induction that either $i=0$ or $i=d$.

For $i=0$: It follows that $x_j = x_{j-1}\frac{x_1}{x_0}$ , for $1\leq j \leq d$.

So we let $z=\frac{x_1}{x_0}$ and it follows that
\begin{align*}
\langle x_0,\cdots, x_d\rangle &= \langle x_0,zx_0,z^2x_0,\cdots,z^dx_0\rangle\\
&=v_d(\langle 1,z\rangle)
\end{align*}

Could anyone tell me how to then proceed with the case $i=d$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, I figured it out :)